# Noncommutative extension of algebra of smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ denote the algebra of smooth real functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $j : \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \rightarrow A$ be the injective homomorphism sending a polynomial to its corresponding function.

Let $\mathbb{R}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$ denote the algebra of real-coefficient polynomials in the *freely non-commuting* variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$;
and let $q : \mathbb{R}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the obvious surjective homomorphism sending each $x_i$ to $x_i$.

My question is whether there exist a real algebra (associative, unital, not commutative) $B$,
and (real-linear, unital) homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle \xrightarrow{f} B
\xrightarrow{g} A$, such that $g \circ f = j \circ q$ and $g$ is surjective and $f$ is injective?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is, but you can always take
$$
B=\mathbb{R}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle\oplus A,
$$
and
$$
f(\varphi)=(\varphi,(j\circ q)\varphi),\qquad\qquad g(x,y)=y.
$$

Comment: I guess this is technically true but I assume the OP's goal is to ask whether it makes sense to talk about "noncommutative smooth functions" in $n$ variables. E.g. there is a perfectly sensible notion of noncommutative formal power series in $n$ variables, given by completing noncommutative polynomials suitably, and inside this ring we can isolate various subrings of convergent power series.